# Проблемы при установке GitLab на Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu

Добрый день, устанавливаю GitLab (клон GitHub) на сервер под управлением ОС Ubuntu Server 13.10, делал все как написано тут - http://www.linuxspace.org/archives/4748 . Выполнил все инструкции, потом пытаюсь запустить службу командой **sudo service gitlab start**, но возникает ошибка:

> Starting both the Gitlab Unicorn and Sitekiq /etc/init.d/gitlab : 171:
>   /etc/init.d/gitlab : script/web : not found

и

> /etc/init.d/gitlab :178: /etc/init.d/gitlab : script/background_jobs : not found

Может кто-то сталкивался? Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Я через thin поднимал, пришлось через su и еще какие-то костыли прыгать, sudo service по умолчанию не работал. У вас здесь похоже на то, что где-то потеряна директория приложения, и скрипт не может найти то, что хочет запустить. Попробуйте сделать то же самое, зайдя в папку приложения.

Comment: были проблемы при установке из гитхаб репы, там было чтото типа пыталось запустить sidekiq, но по мануалу был установлен не он, а unicorn вроде. Проверяйте что запускает скрипт запуска и что стоит в реале.

Comment: sidekiq, насколько понял - это демон задач, а unicorn - такой же сервер, как и thin. Я не мастак в руби, но, насколько знаю, это вообще несвязанные вещи.

Comment: вообще похоже на то, что не может директории найти, хз, я б посмотрел что там на этой строке находится и что для чего проверяется

Comment: Статья-руководство 2013 года. Не пробовали поставить с официального сайта?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как устаревшего и неактуального.